# Cохранить значение $_POST в базу данных с помощью PDO

Tags: pdo, post

Привет.

У меня есть форма с полем: Имя

```
<input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя">
```

Получаю имя так:

```
//получаем имя  
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Подключился к базе данных:

```
    try {
      $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $db->exec("set names utf8");

    // Создать таблицу
      $sgl = "CREATE TABLE users_name (
        id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        created DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',

        PRIMARY KEY (id)
      )";
      if($db->exec($sgl) !== false) echo 'Таблица создана!';
      //Закрытие соединения
  $db = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Всё работает, только не могу понять, как записать Имя пользователя в базу данных. И сравнение, если такое имя уже существует в Базе данных, вывести сообщение: Такое имя уже есть.

**P.S.**
Может, на примере пойму логику.

Answer (score 2):

```
//фильтрация данных
$name = ...;
//...
$QUH = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM users_name WHERE name=:name');
$QUH->bindParam(':name',$name);
$QUH->execute(); 
if($QUH->rowCount()==0) { 
    $QUH = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users_name (name,...) value (:name, ...)');
    $QUH->bindParam(':name', $name);
    //все параметры(кроме id)
    $QUH->execute();
    //$id = $db->lastInsertId(); - если нужно узнать присвоенный AUTO_INCREMENT
    $msg = 'регистрация завершена';
} else {
    $msg = 'имя уже используется'; 
}
```

Comment: Здорово, спасибо.

Comment: Сравнение не происходит,   

$QUH->execute();
    //$id = $db->lastInsertId(); - если нужно узнать присвоенный AUTO_INCREMENT
    $msg = 'регистрация завершена';
} else {
    $msg = 'имя уже используется'; 
}
не работает!

Comment: для lastInsertId() есть ограничение до какой-то версии PHP...

Comment: @rooty, @Viher имеет в виду, что у него само условие всегда выполняется одинаково

Comment: @Viher у вас в коде после подключения к бд оно сразу закрывается: 

    $db = null;

Comment: @rooty
lastInsertId() закомментил.
 
@Etki 
Если в поле повторно ввести Имя в базе нечего не меняется, не время не id.  

@rooty

$db = null; - после подключения к бд закрывается после записи в бд Имя. Я не нашел инфы о rowCount - это что?

Comment: @Viher да с ним могут быть проблемы для SELECT

Посмотри "Пример2": http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @rooty 
Понял, но должен работать. Что вместо точек в ваше примере (name,...)? 
Я смотрю пример http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php 19
и не могу понять, как PDO улучшает работу с бд.

Comment: @Viher $_POST, $_GET или $_REQUEST, то, откуда вы берёте данные($name)!